# Android/Google Analytics SDK : how to make REAL TIME analytics working?

Tags: android, sdk, google-analytics, real-time, analytics

I installed the Google Analytics SDK in my app.

I want to be able to have real time analytics (new feature proposed by Google).

My code:

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
// the tracker is started with a dispatch interval of 20 seconds.
tracker.startNewSession("UA-XXXXX", 20, theContext);
tracker.trackEvent("Init", theContext.getPackageName(),"NoLabel", 0);
tracker.dispatch();
```

I can follow the "Init" event but the real time stats (giving for example the actual number of users using my app) doesn't work, even if I took can to init my tracker with a dispatch time, and not like this:

```
tracker.startNewSession("UA-XXXX", theContext);
```

Do you know how to solve this issue ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Is the data ultimately appearing in your reports?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use trackPageView if you want it to work with real time Google Analytics. They haven't yet enabled this for events, only for page views, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about trackPageView, please? is it a method, a service, an object... ?